# How to make binding to WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView with Binding, but in the TreeView only 1st level items are shown. I need a treeview =) I broke my head what is wrong.

Here is my code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TreeView Margin="2.996,10,214,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Urls}" Grid.Column="1">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AbsoluteUrl}" Margin="25,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AbsoluteUrl}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**MainViewModel.cs** (part)

```
public ObservableCollection<Url> Urls { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Urls = new ObservableCollection<Url>();
    }
```

**Url.cs**

```
class Url : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Url() { }

    public Url(string absoluteUrl, bool isBroken, string color)
    {
        AbsoluteUrl = absoluteUrl;
        IsBroken = isBroken;
        Color = color;
    }

    enum Status { Working, Broken };

    private ObservableCollection<Url> childUrlsValue = new ObservableCollection<Url>();
    public ObservableCollection<Url> ChildUrls
    {
        get
        {
            return childUrlsValue;
        }
        set
        {
            childUrlsValue = value;
        }
    }

    private string _absoluteUrl;
    public string AbsoluteUrl
    {
        get { return _absoluteUrl; }
        set
        {
            if (_absoluteUrl != value)
            {
                _absoluteUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AbsoluteUrl");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isBroken;
    public bool IsBroken
    {
        get { return _isBroken; }
        set
        {
            if (_isBroken != value)
            {
                _isBroken = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsBroken");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _color;
    public string Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set
        {
            if (_color != value)
            {
                _color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        { 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And just about this i'm adding items to Urls:

```
Url DataGridTopic = new Url(startUrl.ToString(), true, "red");
                    DataGridTopic.ChildUrls.Add(
                        new Url(startUrl.ToString(), true, "red"));
                    DataGridTopic.ChildUrls.Add(
                        new Url(startUrl.ToString(), true, "red"));
                    DataGridTopic.ChildUrls.Add(
                        new Url(startUrl.ToString(), true, "red"));
                    Urls.Add(DataGridTopic);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to tell the **HierarchicalDataTemplate** where to get the child items of a node from by using its [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemssource.aspx) property.

In your case:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
     DataType="{x:Type my:Url}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildUrls}"
>
         ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Note also the usage od the **DataType** attribute, which often will become a necessity if the levels of the tree are made of different object types (a tree of directories and files would be such an example). However, i am not sure whether this would apply to your scenario or not.

Comment: Where i need to paste this?

Comment: @user2932802, are you able to read and understand your own XAML given in your question?